# Google Font no funciona en CSS externo

Tags: html, css3, fuentes, google-fonts

Llevo un tiempo intentando aplicar la fuente [Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) en un proyecto con HTML, CSS y el framework [Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/).

Link para importar la fuente:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

El problema es que sólo funciona con el CSS3 utilizándolo en la forma [Internal Style sheet](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

Código:

- De esta forma funciona (añadiendo el elemento style al HTML):

  ```
      <style type="text/css">
      h1 {
         font-family: Open Sans;
      }
      </style>
  ```
- De esta otra forma (en el archivo .css) no:

  ```
    h1 {
      font-family: Open Sans;
    }
  ```

He probado los diferentes imports:

```
 <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
 </style>
```

Según lo que he encontrado, también he probado a quitar el http:, con @font-face pero sigue sin darme resultado. Alguna idea?

Head del HTML:

```
  <head>
     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
     <title>Portfolio Webpage</title>
     <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fe361c97c5.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
     <link href="C:\DESARROLLO WEB\FrontEnd\BOOTSTRAP\bootstrap-3.3.7-
      dist\css\bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
     </script>
 </head>
```

Comment: Estuve probando y si me funciona fijate

Comment: Es probable estés teniendo un 404 con la fuente.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que el problema es que te faltan las comillas en el css:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>Open sans</h1>
<p>Otra letra</p>
```

La otra posibilidad es que bootstrap esté pisando tu elección de fuente, en ese caso seguramente sea suficiente con ubicar tu css al final.

Otra opción es customizar bootstrap utilizando sass o less.

Comment: Con comillas lo he probado, simples y dobles. Pero creo que lo de ponerlo al final no lo he hecho, voy a probarlo gracias.

Comment: Con o sin comillas igual se renderiza; sin embargo lo recomendado es siempre usar comillas.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado la solución:
Sólo he tenido que mover el import del archivo .css por encima del import del Bootstrap.